# How to use searchbar in a dropdown list in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to make a registration form in which I have a dropdown list of countries which is very large in size. I want to include search option on top of dropdown list to provide ease of access. Can anyone help me out with this? Here's my code:

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>

<form [formGroup]="myForm">   
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Dropdown1 :</ion-label>
        <ion-select formControlName="dd" (ionChange)='f($event)'  #dd>
            <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
            <ion-option value='1'>A</ion-option>
            <ion-option value='2'>B</ion-option>
            <ion-option value='3'>C</ion-option>
            <ion-option value='4'>D</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>



</form> 
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  function f(event){
  alert(event);

  }

}
```

Comment: hi, did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach to this problem. Instead of using dropdown list for selecting a country, you can use this cool `ng2-bootstrap` feature called **TYPEAHEAD**. How does it work? You have simple input field and all you need to do is simply start typing name of your country, even one character is enough and list pops up, or you can make list pop up on click and then filter results when user types something. I suggest adding a `placeholder` as well so users will have better understanding of how this works, maybe "Start typing and your country will pop up", or something like that. You can check how it works [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/typeahead) and you can find instructions for installing `ng2-bootstrap` [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/).

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your help

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general. I'd suggest you asked something that you can't handle after you try to accomplish your task.

Anyway there is the exact same example you're trying to do in [Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar)

UPD:

Taking into account your comments and question update the best solution would be to create your custom component with search bar and a list of items with checkboxes. You can make it to be a dropdown, or show it in an ionic modal component. You can make it work with ngModel or just return selected values.

Comment: I have tried doing it but I am not able achieve anything that's why I did not post the code. And I have referred this link. It is for searching in a list but what i specified is Dropdown list.

Comment: Ok, so where do you want a searchbar? Inside `ion-select`? I don't think this is a good idea to change ionic component.. at least this way.